# How does one package a C library for use in a Cocoa project?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

I have a library that I'd like to use in a Cocoa project, (specifically [vgmstream](https://github.com/kode54/vgmstream)).

To use this, is it as simple as dragging the necessary files into Xcode? Or would I have to build or bundle it in some way in order to use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have built static/shared libraries and the header files, you can easily drag them into the project. Otherwise, you'd have to build the libraries your self, or drag in all the source files to the project.

The so called framework that Xcode uses, is just a folder with .framework extension containing a Headers folder and a static library with it's name the same as the folder name without extension.